# Node.js build system in Sublime Text 2

Tags: javascript, node.js, sublimetext2

I justed started learning JavaScript. While doing that, I got tired of embedding my JavaScript code into an HTML document in order to run it in the browser. I thought it would be nice to just run my scripts right in Sublime's console, so I wouldn't have to leave the editor. Therefore I was trying to create a JavaScript build system, since Sublime doesn't come with one.

My idea was to use Node.js as the JavaScript interpreter. I installed it with the package manager of Linux Mint. As far as I can say it works just fine. Let's say I have a file *test.js* containing the following line of JavaScript code:

```
console.log("Hello World");
```

When I run

```
nodejs /path/to/test.js
```

in my console, I get:

```
Hello World
```

However, I don't get this to work with Sublime. I created a new Build system by clicking *Tools / Build System / New Build System*. I then typed in the following lines:

```
{
    "cmd": ["nodejs", "$file"]
}
```

As far as I know, this one line is the JSON representation of the following command:

```
nodejs /path/to/current/file.ext
```

Like I said, if I run this manually in the console, it works just fine. If I press F7 in Sublime, which is the shortcut for *Build*, Sublime's console shows up. It's empty though.

There's another weird thing. Even though the (non-existing) output of Sublime's console indicates that the build system isn't configured to correctly work with Node.js, I got some Node.js errors displayed when I accidentally tried to run non-JS files such as the *Node.sublime-build* file. This is the output displayed in Sublime's console:

```
/home/baerenfaenger/.config/sublime-text-2/Packages/User/Node.sublime-build:2
    "cmd": ["nodejs", "$file"]
      ^
```

module.js:434
  var compiledWrapper = runInThisContext(wrapper, filename, true);
                        ^
SyntaxError: Unexpected token :
    at Module._compile (module.js:434:25)
    at Object..js (module.js:464:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:353:32)
    at Function._load (module.js:311:12)
    at Array.0 (module.js:484:10)
    at EventEmitter._tickCallback (node.js:190:39)
[Finished in 0.1s with exit code 1]
So why do I not get any output when executing actual JavaScript code? Thank you in advance!

Comment: Sublime doesn't come with a built in one but it sure does come with a package for one you can install...

Comment: Have a look at [SublimeText-Nodejs](https://github.com/tanepiper/SublimeText-Nodejs).

Comment: Thank you @JohnnyHK. I still don't know why my custom build system doesn't work. However, with the package mentioned above I just have to press <i>Alt + R</i> to get exactly the console output that I wanted! This package also gives you the option to tell it where to find Node.js in the PATH. Great!

Comment: Instead of `nodejs` try specifying just `node` in your build system.

Comment: I'm stuck too, nothing seems to work. Please help:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25515319/sublimetext-2-javascript-console

Answer (score 46, accepted):

```
{
    "cmd": ["node","$file"]
}
```

works perfectly for me in windows and it shows the output in the sublime window. Although I dont know how to stop the server after from sublime, I have to search and kill the node process.

Also, check node is in your PATH ;)

Hope it works for you.

Comment: Your solution works for me. I was able to stop the build by using Tools, Cancel Build or Ctrl+Break (Sublime Text 3 tho')

Comment: It works perfectly for me in windows too, but it isnt working in OS X. I have added /ur/local/bin to my PATH but it still isnt working

Comment: @dmeehan I posted this answer almost two years ago and I don't remember if it worked or not in OS X. You can check oozzal's answer which seems to work in OS X. Anyway, I will check this afternoon and update my answer to work with OS X too and with rob's comment, which I totally missed

Comment: You can also set a path (for this build system only), via
`{ "cmd": ["node", "$file"], "path": "/usr/local/bin/" }`
. Works perfectly on OS X.

Answer (score 43):

Mac users, type `which node` in terminal. It outputs the path of the node executable, which in most cases is `/usr/local/bin/node`. Now create a new build system (`Tools > Build System > New Build System`) with the following settings in Sublime Text.

```
{   
  "cmd": ["/usr/local/bin/node", "$file"],   
  "selector": "source.js"   
}
```

Comment: Works on mac as long as you always name your file as `source.js`, or you can change the selector to `"*.js"`

Answer (score 7):

Tested on Ubuntu Linux.  Use a file selector as below:

```
{
  "cmd": ["node", "$file"],
  "selector": "*.js"
}
```

Comment: if no system node binary, (if using nvm), replace "node" above with path/to/nvm/node

Answer (score 4):

Here is a tip for Windows,

Most of the answers from this thread is correct but none is complete and at least no answer tells about how to kill existing Node process even if you are able to run node in sublime. So eventually if either of above approach worked for you, You will end up manually killing Node always.

Here is What I have done for 'Windows':

1. Open Sublime Text, Goto "Tools" -> "Build System" -> "New Build System"
2. Above will open a new file, paste below content there, and save it as nodejs.xxx ( use default extension):
   {
   "cmd": ["c:/test.bat","$file"]
   }
3. Create a file ( c:/test.bat ) and paste this content (both of 2 lines) there:

taskkill /F /IM "node.exe"
"c:/Program Files/nodejs/node.exe" %1

1. Save it, Switch to Sublime Text and select "Tools" -> "Build System" -> "nodejs"
2. open any Nodejs Exectuable file and Hit CTRL+B.
3. You're good to go. :)

Enjoy noding.

Answer (score 3):

The method #2 of the link below solved for me:

http://www.wikihow.com/Create-a-Javascript-Console-in-Sublime-Text

Answer (score 2):

This woks for me in Windows7

1) Open Sublime Text, Goto "Tools" -> "Build System" -> "New Build System"

2) Paste this text

{

```
"cmd": ["C:\\Program Files (x86)\\nodejs\\node","$file"]
```

}

> \\ Escaping character

3) Save as Node.sublime-build

4) Write a new js file, and press CTRL+B for build.

Click [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iLEOq.jpg) for see image example.

Answer (score 1):

Normally

```
"cmd":["node",$file]
```

would work. However there is no way to stop the server than.
I've found out the best solution which opens server in new console and the closes it automatically.
I also works fine with supervisors or node-inspector

```
"cmd" : ["start", "cmd.exe", "/C", "node", "$file"]
```

I hope It'll help

Comment: It gave me errors, with [line:column]: [3:2]. Could you donate a reference link or a breve explanation for comprehend the syntax in build types files for Sublime. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I can only see the console output only if the file exists/saved on disk. (for anonymous file I don't see the output either)

Hope this helps

Answer (score 1):

On Windows, the following configuration works:

```
{
    "cmd": ["C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe", "$file"],
    "selector": "source.js"
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm using windows and I created a New Build System with this content:

```
{
"cmd": ["node", "$file"],
"selector": "source.js",
"working_dir": "${project_path:${folder}}",
"path": "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs"
}
```

And after a ran a JavaScript file with sucessul inside Sublime.

My JavaScript file has this content:

```js
var a = 10;
var b = 20;

var resultado = a + b;

console.log('resultado:', resultado);
```

Answer (score 0):

May be it depends on environment variables -- try to use full path to node instead of just "nodejs".
It worked for me on Mac OS (e.g. /usr/local/node instead of just node)

Answer (score 0):

If all else fails, check Node Supervisor....... you only need to change the code and the server will reboot it self so you can see the changes live =)

Answer (score -1):

On linux I use this, just make sure you are on your main file

```
{
    "shell_cmd": "pkill node ; node $file"
}
```