# SublimeText 2 Javascript console

Tags: javascript, node.js, console, sublimetext2

I'm a SublimeText2 and Javascript newbie, using Windows8.
I'm trying to create a Javascript Console in Sublime Text.

I've tried 2 methods, but none worked with me!

---

METHOD 1:

I've installed "Nodejs Sublime Text 2 Package" found here:
https://github.com/tanepiper/SublimeText-Nodejs

But when I press Alt + R (run current script in node), I just get a message that says:
´kill' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file.

The error message appears in a black windows with the title C:\WINDOWS\system32\cmd.exe", it just appears and disappears in half a second (but I was able to make a print screen).

---

METHOD 2:

I've tried to use a javascript console by installing NodeJS, as instructed here:
http://www.wikihow.com/Create-a-Javascript-Console-in-Sublime-Text see Method 2 of 2: Using Node.js

But when I press Ctrl+B or F7 although the console appears (in bottom area of SublimeText2) and I can read "Building" in the footer information, THE CONSOLE KEEPS COMPLETELY CLEAN, WITH NO RESULTS WHATSOEVER!

---

So I'm stuck! Please help!

Comment: It's not clear what you're trying to do. Do you want a REPL (Read-Eval-Print-Loop) environment where you can execute arbitrary JS commands to be interpreted by Node, or do you want a build system to run a `.js` program with Node?

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand! I just want to see the javascript executed in the console, like I would in Chrome Javascript Console or in Firebug.
If I write:
var a = 5;
var b = 4;
var total = a + b;
console.log(total);

I want to be able to see "9" in the console!

Comment: So you want to take a javascript program, execute it, and see the output?

Comment: Yes, I guess :) But I want to do it inside Sublime Text 2!

Comment: One tip on method 2 is to make sure your file is saved on the system somewhere before you run it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using [SublimeREPL](https://github.com/wuub/SublimeREPL). I have used it quite successfully, although on Win 7.

With tanepiper's plugin, you may have to fiddle with setting paths (I remember them having issues with windows)

```
{
 // if present, use this command instead of plain "node"
  // e.g. "/usr/bin/node" or "C:\bin\node.exe"
  "node_command": false,
  // Same for NPM command
  "npm_command": false,
  // as 'NODE_PATH' environment variable for node runtime
  "node_path": false,

}
```

Comment: How do you see/use the Javascript console in SublimeREPL, when with a javascript file opened?

I've tried to change the paths in tanepiper's plugin, but nothing changed:





`"node_command": "c:/Program Files/nodejs/node.exe",`

Comment: I had a similar problem with "HTML-CSS-JS Prettify" but it was solved by adding a small portion of code to the "HTMLPrettify.py" file of the HTML-CSS-JS Prettify plugin. As seen here: https://github.com/rnoldo/Sublime-HTMLPrettify/commit/bf99fa8d466905f68ccff2ee9f9dda4c8b53d95f

Comment: You can assign a shortcut or open up the REPL via `Tools > SublimeREPL > Node` (node for running JavaScript)

Comment: Ok, I've done that and it opens a tab *REPL*[js]. I do some javascript code, then I press F7 or Ctrl+B. But below only appears [Finished in 0.1s] and nothing else :(

Comment: I'm using SB2 should I change to SublimeText3?

Comment: It executes when you hit `Enter` key. F7, Ctrl+B will again invoke the build system which is not what you want.